# Issues downloading full HTML of webpage with Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm working on a project where I require the all of the game ID #'s found in the current scores section of http://www.nhl.com/ to download content/ parse stats for each game. I want to be able to get all current game ID's in one go, but for some reason, I'm unable to download the full HTML of the page, no matter how I try. I'm using `requests` and `beautifulsoup4`.

Here's my problem:

I've determined that the particular tags I'm interested in are `div`'s where the CSS class = 'scrblk'. So, I wrote a function to pass into `BeautifulSoup.find_all()` to give me, specifically, blocks with that CSS class. It looks like this:

```
    def find_scrblk(css_class):
        return css_class is not None and css_class == 'scrblk'
```

so, when I actually went to the web page in Firefox and saved it, then loaded the saved file in `beautifulsoup4`, I did the following:

```
>>>soup = bs(open('nhl.html'))
>>>soup.find_all(class_=find_scrblk)
[<div class="scrblk" id="hsb2015010029"> <div class="defaultState"....]
```

and everything was all fine and dandy; I had all the info I needed. However, when I tried to download the page using any of several automated methods I know, this returned simply an empty list. Here's what I tried:

- using `requests.get()` and saving the `.text` attribute in a file
- using the `iter_content()` and `iter_lines()` methods of the `request` 
  object to write to the file piece by piece
- using `wget` to download the page (through `subprocess.call()`) 
  and open the resultant file. For this option, I was sure to use the `--page-requisites` and `--convert-links` flags so I downloaded (or so I thought) 
  all the necessary data.

With all of the above, I was unable to parse out the data that I need from the HTML files; it's as if they weren't being completely downloaded or something, but I have no idea what that something is or how to fix it. What am I doing wrong or missing here? I'm using python 2.7.9 on Ubuntu 15.04.

All of the files can be downloaded here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/k6vv8hcxbkwy32b/nhl_html_examples.zip?dl=0

Comment: The page uses Javascript and AJAX to load the data. You should use the developers console of your browser to see the requests and maybe you replicate them. Of cause you would need the permission of nhl.com to use their data at first.

Comment: btw, given your condition, get rid of the `find_scrblk` function, and just use `soup.find_all(class_='scrblk')`

Comment: You will need to find out what request are being sent. You can do it manually and then reproduce it or you could also do it with [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/index.html). Then you could also try scrapping with [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments on your question state, you have to re-think your approach. What you see in the browser is not what the response contains. The site uses JavaScript to load the information you are after so you should look more carefully in the result what you get to find what you are looking for.

In the future to handle such problems try out Chrome's developer console and disable JavaScript and open a site such way. Then you will see if you are facing JS or the site would contain the values you are looking for.

And by the way what you do is against the **Terms of Service** of the NHL website (according to Section 2. Prohibited Content and Activities)

> Engage in unauthorized spidering, scraping, or harvesting of content or information, or use any other unauthorized automated means to compile information;

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I definitely should have looked at their terms of service. I guess I'll just need to do that one part manually >__>